# Problem with BS4 extracting info from a weird class

Tags: beautifulsoup, lxml

Hope anyone with good experience on BS4 can help me. I have a very headache.
I want to get: Product title, price, picture and url from

*https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/category/offspring_catalog/NEWIN?pageSize=100&sort=-releasedate* products.

I have already got `price` and `href (url)` with the following code:

price = `url.find("div", "price js-price")` (PRICE)

Purl = `url.find("a").attrs['href']` (URL)

However picture is giving me problem doing:
picture = `url.find("img").attrs["src"]` and what is more important I don't know how can I get product tittle because it's like in a weird class.

For example on the last item called `Jordan Zoom 92  Trainer`, I would like to get this name , but not sure what I need to do :)

Here is picture if you don´t want to access link.
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXQJg.png)

Thanks a lot <3

Answer (score 1):

To extract the information about each product, you can use this example:

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/category/offspring_catalog/NEWIN?pageSize=100&sort=-releasedate'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for i in soup.select('.productList_item'):
    link = 'https://www.offspring.co.uk' + i.a['href']
    brand = i.strong.text
    name = i.br.find_next_sibling(text=True).strip()
    price = i.select_one('.price, .now_price')['data-value']
    picture_url = json.loads(i.img['data-media'])['350']
    
    print('{:<20} {:<35} {:<10} {:<70} {}'.format(brand, name, price, picture_url, link))
```

Prints:

```
Jordan               Jordan Zoom '92 Trainers            130.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4022015374_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/4022015374
Comme Des Garcons    Cdg Cross Trainers                  535.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4133010000_sd1.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4 https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/4133010000
Comme Des Garcons    Cdg Cross Trainers                  535.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4133000000_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/4133000000
adidas               Paris Trainers                      74.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4022535270_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/4022535270
Nike                 Vapormax 2020 Trainers              190.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4016724556_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/4016724556
Nike                 Vapormax 2020 Trainers              190.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4016724555_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/4016724555
adidas Statement     Hoddlesden Spzl Trainers            50.0       https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/3555150000_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/3555150000
Puma                 Bluebird Trainers                   74.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4033135280_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/4033135280
On-Running           Cloud X Trainers                    130.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4131410508_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/4131410508
On-Running           Cloud Trainers                      120.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4129108801_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/4129108801
On-Running           Cloudswift Trainers                 135.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4128915798_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/4128915798
On-Running           Cloudswift Trainers                 135.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4128908800_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/4128908800
On-Running           Cloudswift Trainers                 135.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4128908799_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/4128908799
On-Running           Cloudswift Trainers                 135.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4128908798_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/4128908798
On-Running           Cloudswift Trainers                 135.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4128908789_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/4128908789
On-Running           Cloudswift Trainers                 135.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4128908788_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/4128908788
Filling Pieces       Low Plain Court Trainers            175.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4122114879_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/4122114879
Filling Pieces       Mondo 2.0 Ripple Trainers           170.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/3556324666_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/3556324666
Filling Pieces       Mondo 2.0 Ripple Trainers           170.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/3556304550_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/3556304550
Filling Pieces       Low Mondo Ripple Trainers           170.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2991230475_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/2991230475
Converse             All Star Hi 70s Trainers            79.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/1662415290_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/1662415290
adidas               Stan Smith Trainers                 74.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2143115498_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/2143115498
adidas Y3            Y-3 Shiku Run Trainers              300.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4084815638_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/4084815638
adidas Y3            Y-3 Shiku Run Trainers              300.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4084808675_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/4084808675
adidas Y3            Y-3 Shiku Run Trainers              300.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4084808673_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/4084808673
adidas               Delpala Trainers                    54.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4037704470_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/4037704470
adidas               Superstar Bold Trainers             89.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2669108370_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/2669108370
adidas               Stan Smith Trainers                 74.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2143115262_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/2143115262
adidas               Stan Smith Trainers                 74.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2143114446_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/2143114446
Converse             All Star Ox 70s Trainers            74.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/1662315290_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/1662315290
adidas               Superstar Trainers                  79.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/3844515498_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/3844515498
Nike                 Air Max 95                          150.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2026496414_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/2026496414
Nike                 Nike Elemental Backpack 2.0         24.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/3891380954_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/3,87/3891380954
adidas               Zx 8000 Trainers                    89.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2125815184_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/2125815184
adidas               Zx 500 Trainers                     74.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2120067342_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/2120067342
adidas               Boston Super Trainers               74.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/1672963106_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/1672963106
adidas               Zx 500 Trainers                     74.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/1511624536_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/1511624536
Puma                 Bluebird Trainers                   74.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4033163114_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/4033163114
Nike                 Space Hippie 4                      125.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4015340811_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/4015340811
Nike                 Space Hippie 1                      115.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/3944508765_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/3944508765
adidas               Padiham Spezials                    74.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/3133467370_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/3133467370
Comme Des Garcons    Spalwart Runners                    275.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4133165000_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/4133165000
Comme Des Garcons    Spalwart Runners                    275.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4133160000_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/4133160000
Comme Des Garcons    Spalwart Runners                    275.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4133140000_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/4133140000
adidas               As 520 Trainers                     74.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4022663107_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/4022663107
adidas               As 520 Trainers                     74.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4022652524_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/4022652524
Jordan               Jordan Delta Trainers               130.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/3936715372_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/3936715372
Nike                 Air Max Plus 3 Trainers             150.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/3777708415_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/3777708415
Nike                 Daybreak Trainers                   89.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/3557108431_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/3557108431
adidas               Stadt Trainers                      84.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/3538480932_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/3538480932
adidas Stella McCartney Ultraboost 20s Trainers             200.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4066340820_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/4066340820
Veja                 Campo Trainers                      115.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/3427115427_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/3427115427
adidas Stella McCartney Treino Trainers                     160.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2901715555_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/2901715555
Vans                 Sk8-Hi Slim Trainers                64.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/1050408494_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/1050408494
adidas Stella McCartney Boston S Trainers                   180.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4065815410_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/4065815410
adidas Stella McCartney Boston S Trainers                   180.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4065808567_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/4065808567
Vans                 Sk8 Hi Mte 2.0 Dx Trainers          100.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4027396439_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/4027396439
Vans                 Old Skool Trainers                  74.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2421896435_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/2421896435
Nike                 Air Max III Trainers                130.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4016615343_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/4016615343
adidas               Zx8000 Trainers                     110.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2164415678_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/2164415678
Jordan               Air Jordan Og Trainers              125.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/3873703617_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/3873703617
Jordan               Jordan Zoom '92 Trainers            130.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4022008450_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/4022008450
Nike                 Nike Flow 2020 Ispa Trainers        155.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4063667382_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/4063667382
Nike                 Nike Flow 2020 Ispa Trainers        155.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4063666824_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/4063666824
Puma                 Puma Oslo Trainers                  79.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/1352112146_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/1352112146
Puma                 Puma Oslo Trainers                  79.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/1352111797_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/1352111797
adidas               Sl 72 Trainers                      69.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/3843115257_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/3843115257
Nike                 Air Force 1 07 Trainers             110.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2704615626_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/2704615626
Vans                 Vans Classic Slip Ons               54.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2496515408_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/2496515408
Jordan               Air Jordan 6 Trainers               170.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/1642387429_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/1642387429
Nike                 Air Max 90 Flyease Trainers         115.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4020803617_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/4020803617
Nike                 70's Type Trainers                  79.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4015815319_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/4015815319
adidas Y3            Y-3 Sprint Trainers                 250.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4003101110_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/4003101110
Jordan               Jordan Delta Trainers               115.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/3936724545_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/3936724545
adidas Y3            Y-3 Yohji Star Trainers             229.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/3887100000_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/3887100000
adidas Y3            Y-3 Yohji Pro Trainers              229.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/3886900000_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/3886900000
Nike                 Air Force 1 07 Trainers             84.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2583208441_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/2583208441
Nike                 Blazer Mid 77 Trainers              89.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/1174377157_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/1174377157
Converse             Run Star Hike Trainers              89.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/3543677146_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/3543677146
Converse             Run Star Hike Trainers              89.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/3543640809_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/2,20/3543640809
Jordan               Air Jordan 3                        170.0      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/1641815508_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/1641815508
adidas               Zx 1000 Trainers                    74.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4095915679_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/4095915679
Vans                 Backpack                            46.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4028396449_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/3,87/4028396449
Vans                 Crew Socks                          12.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4028296448_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/3,87/4028296448
Vans                 Ss T-shirt                          46.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4028196446_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/3,87/4028196446
Vans                 Shallow Unstructed Cap              27.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4028096445_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/3,87/4028096445
Vans                 Sk8 Low Trainers                    64.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/4027296438_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/4027296438
Vans                 Comfycush Slip On Trainers          69.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/3823196432_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/3823196432
Vans                 Sk8 Hi Zip Toddler Trainers         39.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2838496436_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/4,85/2838496436
Vans                 Authentic Kids Trainers             36.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2615596440_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/4,85/2615596440
Vans                 Classic Slip On Kids Trainers       36.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2608196443_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/4,85/2608196443
Vans                 Classic Slip On Toddlers            32.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2607396442_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/4,85/2607396442
Vans                 Classic Slip On Toddlers Trainers   32.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2607396441_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/4,85/2607396441
Vans                 Old Skool Trainers                  69.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2421896434_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/2421896434
Vans                 Sk8 Hi Trainers                     74.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2421696437_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/2421696437
Vans                 Sk8 Hi Trainers                     74.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2421696436_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/2421696436
Vans                 Era Trainers                        59.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2209196433_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,21/2209196433
Vans                 Sk8 Hi Kids Trainers                49.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/1834196436_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/4,85/1834196436
Converse             Jack Purcell Trainers               84.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2413215636_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/2413215636
Converse             Jack Purcell Trainers               84.99      https://i1.adis.ws/i/office/2413208670_ls.jpg?$picture$&version=6.0.4  https://www.offspring.co.uk/view/product/offspring_catalog/5,22/2413208670
```